# Strange problem with MySQL full text query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

This probably has something to do with my understanding of full text search or perhaps a known issue. My Java code creates search term for full text search on MySQL like this -

+word*

This works fine if the value in the DB column contains more text than the word itself. However, if the value is exact - no result are returned. I expected it to return results when value is an exact match. Let me give an example -
Assume that DB has column name with value "Manish", now if I search with this -
+Manis*

It does return the result correctly, but if I try this -
+Manish*
It doesn't return any result, though exact match exists in DB column - Name. How can I obtain the desired behaviour in both these cases? Removing + sign works, but it returns far too many results when there are two or more words.

Any help, pointers would be highly appreciated! I am using MySQL 5.0

TIA, 
- Manish

Comment: It should work the way you are doing it, as long s you re not searching for stopwords or words shorter than ft_min_word_len. Make sure you are running the queries IN BOOLEAN MODE. What is your setting for ft_min_word_len?

Comment: ft_min_word_len is set to 3. That's not a problem and rest of the things are fine as well. As I mentioned in the post itself, removing "+" works, but then it implies "OR" condition and when I give 2 or more words for search - it ends up giving far too many results than what I'd like to have with "AND".

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the +
+Man  searches for Man but not Manish
Man* searches for Man and Manish.

Comment: Removing + gives to many results for multiple words, as it implies "OR" condition.